# Why does REST Response not end the execution?

Tags: php, rest, fuelphp

In FuelPHP when using Controller_REST I can't use \Response as REST controller has its own Response functions using $this->response...

But when I execute this function and pass a body and a response code.

```
$this->response(array("Missing Parameter"), 400);
```

Like so, this doesn't actually end the execution and the function calling it carries on. If I use

```
exit;
```

The Response is broken. Does anyone know why this happens or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `return;` instead of `exit;`. Usually you do not want to stop everything but just the execution if your business logic.